# How to solve column id not found in springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to get registration details from user and added a logic in spring boot that if email is already exist then throw error. So, when I register with new mail springboot is working fine but when I try with existed mail it shows status 500 error from server. In server, the error is `column id` not found.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SessionHandlingRepository extends JpaRepository<SessionHandling, Integer>{

    @Query(value="Select email from session_handling where email= :email",nativeQuery =true)
    public SessionHandling findByEmailId(@Param("email")String email);
    
    @Query(value="Select email, password from session_handling where email= :email AND password= :password",nativeQuery =true)
    public SessionHandling findByEmailIdAndPassword(@Param("email")String email, @Param("password")String password);
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class SessionHandling {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String cpassword;
public SessionHandling(int id, String name, String email, String password, String cpassword) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.cpassword = cpassword;
} //all getter and setter
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
private SessionHandlingService service;


@PostMapping("/register")
public SessionHandling addUser(@RequestBody SessionHandling registration) throws Exception {
    String tempEmailId = registration.getEmail();
    if(tempEmailId != null && !"".equals(tempEmailId)) {
        SessionHandling UserObj = service.fetchUserByEmailId(tempEmailId);
        if(UserObj != null) {
            throw new Exception("user with " +tempEmailId+ "already exist");
        }
    }
    SessionHandling UserObj = null;
    UserObj = service.addUser(registration);
    return UserObj;
}
```

Error

> 2022-06-11 11:28:39.677 ERROR 8032 --- [nio-9197-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute query; SQL [Select email from session_handling where
> email= ?]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]
> with root cause
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.

Comment: What does this have to do with angular?

Comment: Using this method findByEmailId, do you want to select the entire SessionHandling object or just the email string?

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the respective table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Query(value="Select email from session_handling where email=
> :email",nativeQuery =true) public SessionHandling
> findByEmailId(@Param("email")String email);

As per the repository method declaration mentioned by you, the following change require to your `Query` in order to correct the issue. As per your code you want to return `SessionHandling` complete object to service class.

```
@Query(value="Select * from session_handling where email= :email",nativeQuery =true)
```